# C#: Make new api calls to get new responses

Tags: c#

I'm using text generation API and I want to generate a new response each time, which was not the case in my side.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //make a request to URI
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/gpt2");

            //Input data
            var postData = "My name is Thomas and my main";

            //encoding the input to type byte    
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            //send a POST request to the api
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Set the content length of the string being posted
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            // get the stream of the request
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //Print the generated text of "generated-text"
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(responseString);
        }
    }
```

So as far as I understood the call is getting cached.
How can I stop this from happening ? So that I get a new response each time I call the api

Comment: Why are you declaring a HttpClient object, set some of its headers, then you initialize and use a HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Was using an old method, I deleted it

Comment: You're using an old method now :) `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but somehow still getting the same response

Comment: Well, I don't know what *the same response* means in this context (given that you're apparently sending the same request). I have no idea what that API is for; maybe check again its documentation.

Comment: I'm using this one : https://huggingface.co/gpt2?text=My+name+is+Thomas+and+my+main if you click on compute, it will always generate a new response

Comment: The caching feature is part of the API, not the WebRequest. You have to specify `{use_cache : false}` as parameter, sending a JSON body, as in `{"inputs": "Some text", "parameters": {"use_cache": false}}` -- `"inputs"` is mandatory, `"parameters"` could `"options"` in this kind of request, [check the documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/api-inference/detailed_parameters)